# DudaOne - Access JavaScript section in head

Tags: javascript, content-management-system

I'm using this CMS called DudaOne and am trying to move some code around in Developer Mode. I want to access the JavaScript section of the head - the one I can see in FireBug - and move it to another part of the document but I can't find the JS section anywhere in Developer Mode.

Anyone know how to access that?

Answer (score 0):

From the [support documentation](https://support.dudamobile.com/02DudaOne/How-To/Header_Section), it looks like you can access the header HTML for sites in this CMS via the 'header HTML' section under 'site settings'.

It also looks like there's a site HTML / CSS option in the CMS which has a head-section.html file you can access as well.

Comment: It seems that the code I'm trying to find is not available in either of those locations, unfortunately. I'm not sure it's accessible at all.

Answer (score 0):

So, after emailing with technical support staff from the developers of DudaOne I've found out that the code that I was trying to access is not made available to clients or even support staff.